# Android activity transition launcher background flashes

Tags: android, android-activity

Sometimes, when a transition from one to another activity happens in my application, the device launcher's background briefly flashes in the middle of the transition. It is quite disturbing.

How to avoid that background flash in the middle of activity transition?

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to this [image: Activity lifecycle concept]

You can handle the transition better once you understand how the lifecycle works.